# converting HTML for handheld

Tags: html, css, handheld

Okay, I browsed through a few topics here, but there was no definite answer. Could someone please guide me?

**CSS:**

```
body {
background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: #EEEEEE;
font-family: Andalus;
}
a{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
h1 {
font-family: Andalus;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shipping Verification System</title>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="web.css"  type="text/css" media="Screen"/>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="web.css"  type="text/css" media="handheld"/>
</head>
```

How can I convert this into handheld format? Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have separate css files or just one css file with media queries. Using media queries you can have different UIs for both desktop as well as handheld devices. 
Read this for more info http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/